# Changing content using $_POST

Tags: php, forms, post

im trying to change the value of a field in $_POST so that it will load the correct content for whatever has been posted.

When a user goes onto my website $_POST is initially set as

`$_POST['order_page_content'] = 'list'`

I then have a form in my view.content.php file that looks like this:

```
<td><form action='http://localhost/magento_soap_client/fulfilment' method='POST'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='order_page_content' value='info'/>
                        <input type='hidden' name='order_id' value='$order_info->order_id'/>
                        <input type='submit' value='View'/>

                        </form></td></tr>";
```

So the value of $_POST['order_page_content'] should change to info when the button is clicked. Therefore the content of the page should change...

Once the button is clicked, i can see via firebug that the value has changed in the post, its just my page isn't getting set to it

So how do i make the content change based on the post value that got submitted? Or what is going wrong?

**EDIT**

Ok guys ive tried what you said, but its still not happening, i dont know if i have put it in the wrong place or what... i think the easiest way is to show you my code.

The script to decide which content it is is here:
[link](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:382a)

and the script that calls it is here:

```
public function get_html() {
    $m_html = null;

    if($_POST['order_page_content'] == 'list'){
    $m_obj_html = new content();
    $m_html = $m_obj_html->get_page_content('list');
    }
    else if($_POST['order_page_content'] == 'info'){
        $m_obj_html = new content();
        $m_html = $m_obj_html->get_page_content('info');
    }

    return $m_html;
}
```

The post['order_page_content'] is getting set in the bootstrap initially to list

Thanks

Comment: Do i understand that right, you have one page and you want to load the content of e.g. info into that page?

Comment: Yes to start with it has the content of list in the page, then when the user clicks the button the content will be changed to info

Comment: I have just edited the post with more info

Answer (score 0):

Tom You can check it with the use of if condition

```
if($_POST['order_page_content']=="info"){some code} else { some code}
```

Comment: I hve tried this in my bootstrap file, the first and only file that gets called after the index, but still the post is holding 'list'?

Comment: why do you want to set POST variable every time. Just make the case of if..else and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='hidden' name='order_id' value='<?php echo $order_info->order_id; ?>'/>
```

if it's already in php use

```
<input type='hidden' name='order_id' value='". $order_info->order_id ."'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is set globally from PHP.

If you have something in your script like:

```
$_POST['order_page_content'] = 'list';
```

So your variable is on each page load overwritten.
Try to check for it before you set it.

```
if (!array_key_exists('order_page_content', $_POST)
{
    $_POST['order_page_content'] = 'list';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is set with post data sent from the client when they access the site. You can access it if they send any. Your form looks like it should work. What I do see though is that you make them send this against a page on the localhost. Is localhost running an apache or similar server with PHP? If it is, then on that page add this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['order_id'])){
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

If that form is on the page you send them to, and you want the value to be remembered (still be there after they send in the form/post data, then do this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='order_id' value='<?php if(!empty($_POST['order_id'])) echo $_POST['order_id']; ?>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was this line:

```
<form action='http://localhost/magento_soap_client/fulfilment' method='POST'>
```

The url in action was resetting everything, so i have now taken it out and left action blank and works fine

Thanks for your help though guys